# Issue with modal box and nic editor

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have taken a modal box on "add ticket" link in my project. Modal box contains a text-area which is a nic editor. when I click on save, the modal box is not closing and the main page is not refreshing.

```
<script src="js/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
//
 function addArea2()
 {
  area2 = new nicEditor({fullPanel : true}).panelInstance('txtcountry1'); 
 } 
 bkLib.onDomLoaded( function()    {
   addArea2();
 }); 
</script>
```

Comment: you have to post a working code so we can examine it

Comment: <script src="js/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    function addArea2() {
        area2 = new nicEditor({fullPanel : true}).panelInstance('txtcountry1');
  }
  
  bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { addArea2(); });
  //]]>
    </script>

Comment: you have to edit the post and add the code there instead posting it in a comment. Additionally, this is not a working code

Comment: I am using nic editor for text area because I want to make some text colored.

Comment: Add the code inside your Question not here, code is un-readable in comments section @priyankapatil

Comment: yes I have added